Azure private dns zone resolves private endpoints in multiple region Vnet
I have azure file storage. And app service deployed to two region, each app service has it's own Vnet. App service has different resource name for each of the region. Subscription is same.
I created private endpoints in each of the region of the app service, inside their respective Vnet.
Private endpoints is deployed to the Vnet of each of the region.
Also created private dns zone for the file storage. So, there are two private dns zone with resource group of the app service, and private ip of the file storage for the particular region only.
Both the Vnets are linked to this private dns zone.
I learnt that the private dns zone is a global resource
How does azure resolve to the private ip of the storage from the Vnet of the particular region? Given private dns zone is a global resource.
Does private dns zone stores A records per region per Vnet?
